# AdminCtrl is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict? angular meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Error Snapshot Development when using ng-strict-di

[image: Error Snapshot Development when using ng-strict-di]

I am developing project in meteor , If I don't use ng-strict-di in development it works fine but then in production(after making build ) I face following issue :

Error In Production Meteor

[image: Error In Production Meteor]

**Development Error:**

> Error columnNumber: 12 fileName:
>   "localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6"
>   lineNumber: 895 message: "[$injector:strictdi] AdminCtrl is not using
>   explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict
>   mode\nerrors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$injector/strictdi?p0=AdminCtrl"
>   stack:
>   "minErr/<@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:895:12\nannotate@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:5039:17\ninjectionArgs@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:5833:21\ninvoke@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:5868:18\n$controllerInit@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:11846:24\nnodeLinkFn@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:10709:35\ncompileTemplateUrl/<@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:11117:13\nprocessQueue@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:17939:37\nscheduleProcessQueue/<@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:17987:27\n$digest@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:19122:15\n$apply@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:19419:13\nbootstrapApply@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:2737:9\ninvoke@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:5876:16\ndoBootstrap@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:2735:5\nbootstrap@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:2755:12\nangularInit@localhost:3007/packages/modules.js?hash=f352b06ef868d8ef612a0e02d3fc1da778e4f6d6:2640:5\nangular.js/proto: Object { … }

**Production(Build )**

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t
>   errors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t
>   Stack trace:
>   r/<@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:7828
>   he/b.$injector<@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:30527
>   r@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:29436
>   he/E<@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:30610
>   r@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:29436
>   i@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:29741
>   a@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:29962
>   t@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:12:25404
>   p@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:12:11871
>   ht/<@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:12:17718
>   u@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:13:15438
>   l/<@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:13:15884
>   $digest@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:13:21599
>   $apply@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:13:23411
>   t@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:16603
>   a@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:30066
>   a@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:16522
>   lt@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:16810
>   ct@localhost:3008/7084ab3720bb9d2b53502cd2b81dce478c095b4c.js?meteor_js_resource=true:11:16046
>   angular.js/

Comment: node version : 4.5.0
meteor  : METEOR@1.4.1.3

Comment: Do not paste images of source code or error messages! Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, just for fun and in case you're an idiot like me, ensure you have `$inject` and not `inject` when you think that you are properly annotating your dependencies. /sigh

Answer (score 3):

You're bootstrapping Angular in [strict dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp#with-ngstrictdi-) mode. This causes angular to throw exceptions when it encounters a dependency that isn't explicitly annotated. This is a way to enforce developers to guard against  names of dependencies getting minified.

*From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):*

> If this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be
>   created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail
>   to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and
>   are thus unsuitable for minification), as described in the Dependency
>   Injection guide, and useful debugging info will assist in tracking
>   down the root of these bugs.

The error tells you that you havn't explicitly annotated your `AdminCtrl`-controller. To fix this, your code should look similar to this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('AdminCtrl', ['firstDependency', 'secondDependency', 
   function(firstDependency, secondDependency){
       // Controller body
   }]);
```

or using `$inject`:

```
angular.module('app').controller('AdminCtrl', AdminCtrl);

AdminCtrl.$inject = ['firstDependency', 'secondDependency'];
function AdminCtrl(firstDependency, secondDependency){
    // Controller body
}
```

The second method can be done for you automatically if you use build tools such as grunt, gulp or webpack, along with the `ngAnnotate` package.